# is the print statement correct?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to add str(iterMul(a,b)) to obtain what I want. Is it the proper way to do it?

```
def iterMul(a,b):
    result = 0
    while b > 0:
        result += a
        b -=1
    return result
a=int(raw_input('Enter an integer: '))
print('')
b=int(raw_input('Enter an integer: '))
print('')
print (str(a) + ' times '+str(b)+' is equal to '+ str(iterMul(a,b)))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the point of `print('')`? Why not just use endline characters (such as `\n`)?

Comment: Formatting is the right way to go. But a quick and easy version is to use `,` instead of `+` to combine items to print: `print a, ' times ', b, ' is equal to ', iterMul(a,b)`

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND: Good question, but the followup is a bit confusing. `print('\n')` will print _two_ blank lines. I think what you want is just `print()` (for Python 3) or `print` (for Python 2). (By the way, I _have_ seen people use `print('')` because it's the shortest thing that prints a single blank line in both Python 2 and 3… but I don't think the OP was doing that.)

Comment: @abarnert33 - i believe he meant to just add the newline characters to the string to be printed...

Comment: @abarnert That is what I meant. That if you want to print two things, with a line in between, you can do: `print('line1\n\nline2')`. The first `\n` puts the cursor at the next line, and the next one does the same. Thus, it will print `'line1'` on a line, have an empty line in between, and then print `'line2'`.

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND: OK, I see what you mean. But with `raw_input`, you have to think about the implicit newlines that come from the user, which makes it less obvious what's going on, at least for new users. So I don't think there's anything wrong with what the OP is doing. (Except for using `print('')` instead of just `print`—unless he's explicitly trying to write 2-and-3-compatible code, this is just more verbose and harder to read.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) instead:

```
print '{0} times {1} is equal to {2}'.format(a, b, iterMul(a,b))
```

String formatting automatically transforms integers to string when interpolating the values, and is more readable than `print value, ' some text ', othervalue, ' more text and ', thirdvalue`.

Comment: As someone pointed out in the comments, string formatting is not needed here: One can just pass more arguments to `print`.

Comment: @delnan: certainly, but string formatting is usually a better idea anyway.

Comment: I have to disagree. It adds needless nesting and complexity -- the multi-argument version is flatter and at least as readable for me.

Comment: I suspect the OP is using Python 3, not 2. If so, both this code and the comment will raise a `SyntaxError`. But this code has the advantage that just wrapping it in parentheses makes it work with both 2 and 3 at the same time—while with the comment version, wrapping it in parentheses will make 2 print an ugly `tuple` `repr` instead of the intended nice string.

Comment: @abarnert: It was originally tagged with just `python-2.7`. It is *not* a good idea to wrap the expression in parenthesis on Python 2; `print (1, 2)` will print something completely different in 2 or 3.

Comment: @abarnert: also: `raw_input` is a Python 2 *only* function.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Good point. But it still looks like code written to be as 2-vs.-3-friendly as possible—in particular, using `print` as if it were a function, even though it isn't, which means you have to always pass it just a single argument. And your answer (along with the original version, but not the comment) does fit into that.

Comment: @abarnert: it is a common beginner mistake to put parenthesis around everything, especially with `print` statements, leading to confusion when using more than one argument to `print`. If you wanted to make your code python 2 and 3 compatible you'd use `from __future__ import print_function` and use it as a proper function.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I write multi-version code all the time, and I never use `from __future__ import print_function`. When I can do everything with single-argument `print`, I do (and when I can't, I either use `six`—and most often, if you need to do complicated things, you're not using `print` in the first place). I'm sure I'm not the only one who does things that way. And that is one of the reasons `format` is sometimes better than multi-argument `print`. (Not the only reason, or even the main one, which is why I just mentioned it in a parenthetical comment to your answer.)

Comment: @abarnert: We are drifting *way* off-topic here; sure there are many ways to skin this cat, and using `from __future__` won't work before python 2.6, so if you wanted to support 2.5 or before you wouldn't have the choice anyway.